# How to query the socket type of a file descriptor?

Tags: sockets, unix, file-descriptor

I have a socket file descriptor (confirmed by fstat(2)). I can use getsockname(2) to query the socket family: getsockname fills the sockaddr.sa_family field. But how do I query the socket type (2nd argument of socket(2)) and protocol (3rd argument of socket(2))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, ...)
getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PROTOCOL, ...)
```

Apparently the former is defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html), whereas the latter might be Linux-specific.  But I don't know whether there's a more portable way to get at the protocol of a socket.